# PDO FETCH_CLASS call __construct passing array

Tags: php, pdo, constructor

I'm having a little trouble with PDO::FETCH_CLASS here. I need it to call the __construct(array $data) passing the array with the values returned from database.

My database is like this:

```
order -> id;
order_item -> id, order_id;
```

And this is how i'm retrieving from database:

```
<?php
public function find($id) {
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM orderItem WHERE id = :id");
    $stmt->setFetchMode(\PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'Store\Model\OrderItem');
    $stmt->execute(array('id' => $id));

    return $stmt->fetch();
}
```

The problem is that PDO::FETCH_CLASS is creating:

```
$orderItem->id;
$orderItem->order_id;
```

Instead of

```
$orderItem->id;
$orderItem->order->id;
```

I made a __construct(array $data) method that would turn:

```
<?php
$orderItem = new OrderItem(
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'order_id' => 10
    )
);
```

into the expected (same as above):

```
$orderItem->id;
$orderItem->order->id;
```

So is there anyway to make PDO call __construct() passing and associative array?

Answer (score 0):

The fetch method `PDO::FETCH_CLASS` returns a new instance of the requested class, mapping the columns to named properties in the class.

Assuming your class Store\Model\OrderItem

```
class Store\Model\OrderItem {  
    public $order;  
    public $order_id;  
    public $otherdata;  //

}
```

To map the values to named properties in your class you need to **JOIN** the 2 tables

```
SELECT orders.id,order_item.order_id
FROM orders, order_item   
WHERE orders.id = order_item.id  
AND order_id =:id
```

See  [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9287ea/2)

I changed order to orders as `ORDER` is a [**Reserved Word**](http://developer.mimer.com/validator/sql-reserved-words.tml)

Comment: Actually my OrderItem class has ($id, $order). And $order type is Order class. What i need is that FETCH_CLASS call my __construct() method passing an associative array instead of setting the data who know how.

Comment: Why use FETCH_CLASS ??

Comment: I think you will need to describe exactly what you want as it is unclear